# RabbitMQ messages reliability for at-least-once delivery

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, microservices, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I wanted to ask what are the possibilities of maintaining reliability when exchanging messages between microservices, when one of those message is rejected. As of today, we don't want to lose messages, so we are re-queueing these rejected messages. Consequently, there is a risk that the messages will be processed in a different order than expected. As a simple example, let's take a simple architecture of two microservices A and B. A publishes two messages one after the other:

```
{"productStatus": "PUSBLISHED", "productId": 1}
{"productStatus": "SOLD", "productId": 1}
```

Microservice B rejects the first message but accepts the second. Due to the fact that we are re-queuing all rejected messages, we are processing the message with the PUBLISHED producer status again, and thus microservice B has incorrect information about the product 1 status.
A simple solution that comes to mind is to add `objectVersionNumber` to each message so that the consumer can tell that he has processed the latest version of the object:

```
{"productStatus": "PUSBLISHED", "productId": 1, "objectVersionNumber": 1}
{"productStatus": "SOLD", "productId": 1, "objectVersionNumber": 2}
```

Are there any other approaches to solving this problem? Perhaps the semantics of the message should completely change?

Comment: You might have to explore the priority queue options along with the prefetch limits

Comment: i dont see anything wrong with objectVersionNumber approach...if the number is less than current discard, as being out of date

Comment: I don't really understand the scenario - why are you rejecting and requeueing messages in the first place? More importantly, I'm not sure this question is a good fit for this site's format  - you have a solution, and want to discuss it with someone, but this isn't a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `prefetch` to 1 will retain the message order (at the expense of performance).